# GridView android layout changes automatically

Tags: android, image, gridview

I created a `GridView` to show all images with some information.
The grid shows the Images and the details.
But when I scroll up and down, arrangement of images changes automatically.
Why is this happening?

**Images.xml**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Grid1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:columnWidth="140dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

**grid_single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"></ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="file"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/path"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="path"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Images.java**

```
public class Images extends Activity {
    GridView grid;
    String[] web = {
            "Google",
            "Github",
            "Instagram",
            "Facebook",
            "Flickr",
            "Pinterest",
            "Quora",
            "Twitter",
            "Vimeo",
            "WordPress",
            "Youtube",
            "Stumbleupon",
            "SoundCloud",
            "Reddit",
            "Blogger"
    };
    String[] imageId = {
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140729_224838.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg",
            "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/final_bstSnapshot_79847.jpg"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.images);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(Images.this, web, imageId);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.Grid1);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Images.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomGrid.java**

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private final String[] web;
    private final String[] Imageid;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] web, String[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(web[position]);

            //////
            Bitmap bm = null;
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Imageid[position], options);
`
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 49, 49);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Imageid[position], options);

            //////

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);//.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok wait i'll share it